# Probability Question in Statistic

Tags: probability, statistics

Individuals in a certain population have a $39\%$ probability of contracting disease $A$ and a $21 \%$ probability of contracting disease $B$, and a probability of $4\%$ of contracting both diseases in their lifetime. If a person in this population contracts at least one of the forementioned diseases, what is the probability he/she will contract both in their lifetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to calculate the probability $P(A\cap B|A\cup B)$ which by the formula of conditional probability is given by $$P(A\cap B|A\cup B)=\frac{P\left((A\cap B)\cap(A\cup B)\right)}{P(A\cup B)}=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A\cup B)}=\frac{0.04}{0.39+0.21-0.04}=\frac{4}{56}$$